# clarification in definition of outward normal derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

While studying about Green's identities from PDE by L.C.Evans I came across the definition of a $C^k$ boundary ( $dU$ ) of a bounded and open set ( $U$ ) in euclidean space . Then comes the following definitions :

1) If $dU$ is $C^1$ , then along $dU$ is defined the outward pointing unit normal vector field $v$ .

2) Let $u  \in  C^1 (\overline U)  $ .We call 
$$ {\partial U \over \partial v} =v.Du$$ 
  the outward normal derivative of $u$.

My questions are:

1) In the first definition , what is the need for $dU$ to be $C^1$ to be able to  define the outward pointing normal vector? I'm not able to relate the definition of a $C^1$ boundary to the fact that we can define an outward pointing normal vector field.

2) Why should $u$ be continuous upto the boundary, when all we need for the definition is the existence of all partial derivatives ?

Comment: For 1), visually if $\partial U$ has a corner then it seems there is no outward pointing unit normal vector at that point.  For 2), maybe this is to guarantee that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}$ behaves as we expect.  For example, we would hope that $\lim_{t \nearrow 0} \frac{u(x + tv) - u(x)}{t} = \frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial v}$.

Comment: Thank you. I get the intuition now. Can you give some reference where I can get the details as well ?

Comment: I think popular books on differentiable manifolds would be a good place to look, but I'm curious which references other people would recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/805656/147263) for an explanation of how  $C^1$ smoothness is used to define the normal vector field. As littleO said, there is not a natural concept of "normal" at a corner of a square, for example.

For question 2): In a smooth domain, the continuity of derivatives up to the boundary implies the continuity of the function up to the boundary (via a form of mean value theorem). So we don't lose anything by making  the definition what it is. Anyway, it is not usually the goal of a mathematician to make definitions as general as possible; they should be as useful as possible. Usefulness and generality are not the same thing, especially when writing a textbook.